# retrieving a specific value from an array code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-variables

I have created the  following session in codeigniter,

```
 $data = array(
                'employee_id' => $row->employee_id,
                'f_name' => $row->f_name,
                's_name' => $row->s_name,
                'user_name' => $row->user_name,
                'title' => $row->title,
                'is_active' => $row->is_active,
                'validated' => true
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata('user', $data);
```

How can I retrieve the  value of `employee_id` from the  session?

I have tried accessing it in a different function the  following way but I keep on getting an error

```
$data = $this->session->userdata('user');

        $data['month'] = $month;
        $data['year'] = $year;

        $this->session->set_userdata('user', $data);
        $data['user_data'] = $this->session->userdata('user');

        var_dump($data);

        foreach ($user_data  as $value) {
            echo $value;
              echo 'Employee ID :'.$value->employee_id.'</br>';
        echo 'Month Session : '.$value->year.'</br>'; 

        }
```

Please advise on the  best way to access it?

Comment: you can access like this `$this->session->userdata('employee_id');`

Comment: See documentation: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 1):

IN Controller, Please call session library

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Now in View

```
$data = $this->session->userdata('user');
$employee_id = $data['employee_id'];
```

Comment: It's bad practice to call the session library in the view.  You should call it in the controller and pass the data to the view

Comment: @Pattle I described above that, `IN Controller`

Comment: No I mean doing `$this->session->userdata('user');` in the view

Answer (score 0):

`$data['user_data'] = $this->session->userdata('user');` will return array of data.

So you can access `$data['user_data']["employee_id"]`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are loading the session library in your controller as its not clear if you are doing that.  You can do this by doing

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

or autoloading it.

Then need to change your code to

```
foreach ($data['user_data'] as $value) {
    echo 'Employee ID :' . $value['employee_id'] . '</br>';
    echo 'Month Session : ' . $data['year'] . '</br>'; 
}
```